# Проблема получения GitHub Access token

Tags: github, auth, oauth

Мне нужно сгенерировать access token для Remix IDE

Я зашел в Github и сгенировал токен, но теперь не понимаю как мне его получить.
Смотрел в других источниках, у них после создания, можно сразу его копировать, у меня же такого нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Его дают посмотреть только один раз после создания, сейчас уже поздно. Сделайте видео, как вы создаёте новый токен.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу HolyBlackCat: вам просто нужно скопировать токен сразу же после его создания (он будет показан сразу после создания), и сохранить его в txt-файл где-нибудь на компьютере.

Comment: Да это знаю, и я смотрел видео как другие создают, но у меня уже был когда то сгенерирован, и сейчас нужен новый, и я его сгенерировал но теперь он не отображается чтоб его скопировать, при этом старая генерация не отображается.